# Scalatest maven plugin: ERROR: -c has been deprecated for a very long time and is no longer supported

Tags: xml, maven, maven-plugin, scalatest, scalatest-maven-plugin

I'm using the [scalatest-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest-maven-plugin) latest 1.0 version, with [source code here](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest-maven-plugin). Trying to run my suites in parallel and using the following configuration:

```
<build><plugin>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version> 
    <configuration>
        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
        <junitxml>.</junitxml>
        <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
        <htmlreporters>${project.build.directory}/html/scalatest</htmlreporters>                    
        <parallel>true</parallel>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin></build>
```

leads to the following Maven build error:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- scalatest-maven-plugin:1.0:test (test) @ myproject ---
Exception in thread "ScalaTest-main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ERROR: -c has been deprecated for a very long time and is no longer supported, to prepare for reusing it for a different purpos
e in the near future. Please change all uses of -c to -P.
        at org.scalatest.tools.ArgsParser$.checkArgsForValidity(ArgsParser.scala:46)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:857)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.main(Runner.scala:827)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.main(Runner.scala)
```

Basically the scalatest-maven-plugin is passing `-c` to the scalatest CLI instead of the correct `-P` .. or even better `-P10` i.e. the number of threads to use.

How can I pass the `-P10` to the scalatest process via Maven? I have tried setting it in the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable or in the Maven CLI directly but it doesn't get picked up.

I have also tried configuring the scalatest-maven-plugin like this:

```
<configuration>
    <argLine>-P10</argLine>
</configuration>
```

but this parameter is passed to the java process and not to the Scalatest so it fails too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created [my own fork of the scalatest-maven-plugin](https://github.com/bravegag/scalatest-maven-plugin), fixed the parallel issue and versioned it as 1.1-SNAPSHOT I had to also fix the build etc it was all broken. I included a directly downloadable compiled tarball version [scalatest-maven-plugin_1.1-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz](https://github.com/bravegag/scalatest-maven-plugin/blob/master/scalatest-maven-plugin_1.1-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz)

Then to test it, forked [my own version of a scala-maven-example](https://github.com/bravegag/scala-maven-example) that uses [my own fork of the scalatest-maven-plugin](https://github.com/bravegag/scalatest-maven-plugin) and modified the scalatest sample code to display the Thread Id that loads each Suite and the Thread Id that executes the first test of each Suite. I also make the current thread sleep in each of those points for a random time up to 10s to see what's going on. All scalatest Suites are loaded by a single thread and executed in parallel if parallel is enabled.

This is the result using `<parallel>false</parallel>`:

```
[INFO] --- scalatest-maven-plugin:1.1-SNAPSHOT:test (test) @ scala-maven-testing ---
Discovery starting.
** loading 'net.lockney.AcceptanceTest' Suite with ThreadId=1
==> executing 'Simple thing state' test with ThreadId=1
** loading 'net.lockney.MatcherExampleSuite' Suite with ThreadId=1
** loading 'net.lockney.SimpleSpec' Suite with ThreadId=1
** loading 'net.lockney.SimpleSuite' Suite with ThreadId=1
Discovery completed in 19 seconds, 98 milliseconds.
Run starting. Expected test count is: 8
AcceptanceTest:
As a user 
I want to be able to create a simple thing and implicitly start it 
So that I can then turn it off 
And see that it is stopped 
Feature: Simple thing state
  Scenario: User stops thing when it's already on
    Given An initialized thing, that has not been started 
    When User stops it again 
    Then We should see that it is stopped 
==> executing 'equality' test with ThreadId=1
MatcherExampleSuite:
- equality
==> executing 'SimpleObject' should 'accept a String' test with ThreadId=1
- string matchers *** FAILED ***
  "something" did not end with substring "some" (MatcherExampleSuite.scala:29)
SimpleSpec:
SimpleObject
- should accept a String
- should even accept really long Strings
==> executing 'An empty Set should have size 0' test with ThreadId=1
...
Run completed in 28 seconds, 300 milliseconds.
Total number of tests run: 8
Suites: completed 5, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 6, failed 2, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
*** 2 TESTS FAILED ***
```

and this is the result using `<parallel>true</parallel>` and `<parallelThreads>10</parallelThreads>`:

```
[INFO] --- scalatest-maven-plugin:1.1-SNAPSHOT:test (test) @ scala-maven-testing ---
Discovery starting.
** loading 'net.lockney.AcceptanceTest' Suite with ThreadId=1
==> executing 'Simple thing state' test with ThreadId=1
** loading 'net.lockney.MatcherExampleSuite' Suite with ThreadId=1
** loading 'net.lockney.SimpleSpec' Suite with ThreadId=1
** loading 'net.lockney.SimpleSuite' Suite with ThreadId=1
Discovery completed in 30 seconds, 904 milliseconds.
Run starting. Expected test count is: 8
MatcherExampleSuite:
SimpleSuite:
AcceptanceTest:
SimpleSpec:
SimpleObject
As a user 
I want to be able to create a simple thing and implicitly start it 
So that I can then turn it off 
And see that it is stopped 
Feature: Simple thing state
==> executing 'An empty Set should have size 0' test with ThreadId=13
==> executing 'SimpleObject' should 'accept a String' test with ThreadId=12
==> executing 'equality' test with ThreadId=11
...
Run completed in 40 seconds, 706 milliseconds.
Total number of tests run: 8
Suites: completed 5, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 6, failed 2, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
*** 2 TESTS FAILED ***
```